# mdadm hardware raid-5 broken after dist-upgrade

Tags: mdadm, hardware-raid

We have intel raid-5 in motherboard, which was assembled in ubuntu as well and mounted as `home` in `fstab`. I read later somewhere I shouldn't use hardware raid in ubuntu. However it was working. But, after dist-upgrade it is broken.

When we used a *live server usb*, it asks two raid activation, one for mdadm, and another for Serial ATA raid. The later is new to me. And then we can unmount and `mount -a` (that uses fstab).

But cannot make it permanent. When *reboot in main system*, by commenting out the `fstab` entry for `/home`, I cannot assemble the RAID. mdadm examine works but detail and assemble fails:

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sd[b-d]
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : 0812e07d
         Family : 0812e07d
     Generation : 000009e6
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : e941dc32:65235e4f:cf333333:3c6f4826
       Checksum : 4b52bbd0 correct
    MPB Sectors : 2
          Disks : 3
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WCC130JX4N8U
          State : active
             Id : 00000001
    Usable Size : 7814026766 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)

[RAIDDISK]:
           UUID : fd8c3145:bac17e65:0ea10271:3138ac34
     RAID Level : 5
        Members : 3
          Slots : [UUU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 0
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 14846574592 (7079.40 GiB 7601.45 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 7423287560 (3539.70 GiB 3800.72 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 28997216
     Chunk Size : 128 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off

  Disk01 Serial : WD-WMC130E3P371
          State : active
             Id : 00000002
    Usable Size : 7814026766 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)

  Disk02 Serial : WD-WMC130E4AW5F
          State : active
             Id : 00000003
    Usable Size : 7814026766 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : 0812e07d
         Family : 0812e07d
     Generation : 000009e6
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : e941dc32:65235e4f:cf333333:3c6f4826
       Checksum : 4b52bbd0 correct
    MPB Sectors : 2
          Disks : 3
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk01 Serial : WD-WMC130E3P371
          State : active
             Id : 00000002
    Usable Size : 7814026766 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)

[RAIDDISK]:
           UUID : fd8c3145:bac17e65:0ea10271:3138ac34
     RAID Level : 5
        Members : 3
          Slots : [UUU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 1
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 14846574592 (7079.40 GiB 7601.45 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 7423287560 (3539.70 GiB 3800.72 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 28997216
     Chunk Size : 128 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WCC130JX4N8U
          State : active
             Id : 00000001
    Usable Size : 7814026766 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)

  Disk02 Serial : WD-WMC130E4AW5F
          State : active
             Id : 00000003
    Usable Size : 7814026766 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : 0812e07d
         Family : 0812e07d
     Generation : 000009e6
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : e941dc32:65235e4f:cf333333:3c6f4826
       Checksum : 4b52bbd0 correct
    MPB Sectors : 2
          Disks : 3
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk02 Serial : WD-WMC130E4AW5F
          State : active
             Id : 00000003
    Usable Size : 7814026766 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)

[RAIDDISK]:
           UUID : fd8c3145:bac17e65:0ea10271:3138ac34
     RAID Level : 5
        Members : 3
          Slots : [UUU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 2
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 14846574592 (7079.40 GiB 7601.45 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 7423287560 (3539.70 GiB 3800.72 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 28997216
     Chunk Size : 128 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WCC130JX4N8U
          State : active
             Id : 00000001
    Usable Size : 7814026766 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)

  Disk01 Serial : WD-WMC130E3P371
          State : active
             Id : 00000002
    Usable Size : 7814026766 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)

$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan -v
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/sdd
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/sdc
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/sdb
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda5
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/sda
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/loop7 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop7
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop7
mdadm: /dev/loop6 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop6
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop6
mdadm: /dev/loop5 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop5
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop5
mdadm: /dev/loop4 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop4
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop4
mdadm: /dev/loop3 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop3
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop3
mdadm: /dev/loop2 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop2
mdadm: /dev/loop1 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop1
mdadm: /dev/loop0 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop0
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop0
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md/RAIDDISK
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/sdd
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/sdc
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/sdb
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda5
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop7
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop6
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop5
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop4
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop3
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop1
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop0
```

Comment: Welcome on the SF! Typically, hardware raid devices are seen like a single device by the OS. If you use mdadm, it is probably software raid.

Comment: @peterh Intel MSM RAID really is software RAID, but managed through the BIOS via an OptionalROM. `mdadm` can manage these "fake hardware" RAID.

Comment: @kaiserasif can you try with `export IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1; mdadm --assemble --scan -v` ?

Comment: @shodanshok I added sudo before mdadm. Not sure if it sees the export from there or not. But same errors. `export IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1; **sudo** mdadm --assemble --scan -v` <br/><br/>
Btw, is there a way to "Activate Serial ATA raid devices" manually? An installation media asks for that, whether installing or live booting. But can we do it from inside a running system?

Comment: I am sorry that it is not a solution, just an advice: 1. *never use fakeraid* 2. *raid doesn't protect from errors in the raid itself, and neither from accidental deletions* 3. *only* backup/archive protects against all of these 4. if you have a new server/system, *the first what you should do is to solve the problem of its automatical backup*, it is more important as its monitoring/alarming! Backup should happen *automatically*, without requiring any human intervention. If the backup needs you, then it is not a backup - data loss happens always unexpected!

Comment: (If it would be expected, then you would obviously avoid it before it happens -> this is why the backup needs to happen always automatically). Data loss is so painful, like the breakup of a romantic relationship.